# Python If statement Invalid syntax but indentation is correct

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to use this [script](https://github.com/underbluewaters/secret-santa/blob/master/secret_santa.py) to set up secret santa. I modified a couple lines so it complies with python 3 but when i run it (under both python2 and python3) i get a syntax error.

Here is some of my code:

```
def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    try:
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "shc", ["send", "help"])
        except getopt.error:
            raise Usage(msg)

        # option processing
        send = False
        for option, value in opts:
            if option in ("-s", "--send"):
                send = True
            if option in ("-h", "--help"):
                raise Usage(help_message)

        config = parse_yaml()
        for key in REQRD:
            if key not in config.keys():
                raise Exception(
                    'Required parameter %s not in yaml config file!' % (key,))

        participants = config['PARTICIPANTS']
        dont_pair = config['DONT-PAIR']
        if len(participants) < 2:
            raise Exception('Not enough participants specified.')

        givers = []
        for person in participants:
            name, email = re.match(r'([^<]*)<([^>]*)>', person).groups()
            name = name.strip()
            invalid_matches = []
            for pair in dont_pair:
                names = [n.strip() for n in pair.split(',')]
                if name in names:
                    # is part of this pair
                    for member in names:
                        if name != member:
                            invalid_matches.append(member)
            person = Person(name, email, invalid_matches)
            givers.append(person)

        recievers = givers[:]
        pairs = create_pairs(givers, recievers)
        if not send:
            print("""
Test pairings:

%s

To send out emails with new pairings,
call with the --send argument:
    $ python secret_santa.py --send

            """ % ("\n".join([str(p) for p in pairs]))

        if send:
            server = smtplib.SMTP(config['SMTP_SERVER'], config['SMTP_PORT'])
            server.starttls()
            server.login(config['USERNAME'], config['PASSWORD'])
        for pair in pairs:
            zone = pytz.timezone(config['TIMEZONE'])
            now = zone.localize(datetime.datetime.now())
            date = now.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %T %Z') # Sun, 21 Dec 2008 06:25:23 +0000
            message_id = '<%s@%s>' % (str(time.time())+str(random.random()), socket.gethostname())
            frm = config['FROM']
            to = pair.giver.email
            subject = config['SUBJECT'].format(santa=pair.giver.name, santee=pair.reciever.name)
            body = (HEADER+config['MESSAGE']).format(
                date=date, 
                message_id=message_id, 
                frm=frm, 
                to=to, 
                subject=subject,
                santa=pair.giver.name,
                santee=pair.reciever.name,
            )
            if send:
                result = server.sendmail(frm, [to], body)
                print "Emailed %s <%s>" % (pair.giver.name, to)

        if send:
            server.quit()

    except Usage, err:
        print >> sys.stderr, sys.argv[0].split("/")[-1] + ": " + str(err.msg)
        print >> sys.stderr, "\t for help use --help"
        return 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

The error arises at line 153 (the line that starts with `if send` and is right after that large block print statement) and it says

```
  File "secretSanta.py", line 153
    if send:
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But i have reason to believe the error is caused by the print statement right above it because when i comment out each section below the print statement the error moves to the next possible line of code.

**Edit:** I am getting a stack overflow causing an abort trap 6. It traces to this block of code:

```
def create_pairs(g, r):
    givers = g[:]
    recievers = r[:]
    pairs = []
    for giver in givers:
        try:
            reciever = choose_reciever(giver, recievers)
            recievers.remove(reciever)
            pairs.append(Pair(giver, reciever))
        except:
            return create_pairs(g, r)
    return pairs
```

specifically the `return create_pairs(g,r) line. I am not sure why the script uses this line to be honest.

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis at the end of the `print` statement on the previous line. Most text editors (including the IDLE that comes with Python) have a bracket matching feature that will make this immediately obvious.

Comment: You should have told us which line is 153…

Comment: sorry, i guess i was assuming that people would paste it into a text editor, but you're right i should have said specificially what it was for those on mobile/etc.

Comment: thanks @kindall i found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line before line 153 (the line shown in error message). Often syntax errors are actually caused by another line than shown in the error message. You are missing a closing parenthesis on line 152.

Comment: thanks! while we are on it, i am also getting an error when i throw exceptions. it doesnt like the comma between the exception type and the msg/err.

Comment: Use `Exception('my message')`.

Comment: thanks! i think its almost fixed. Now i am getting an abort trap: 6 from a stack overflow the trace seems to lead back to line 87 which i did not show so maybe thats another thread? ill add it to the edit in this post just to be safe